# Creating Dynamic List in traditional way vs where multiprocessing is involved

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am studying how Multiprocessing works and would like to generate a list dynamically, connect to a DB , execute a script and tabulate the results. Everything looks goo except the extra layer nesting which is causing the Tabulate to not function he way its expected.

```
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

server_list = ["server-1","server-2","server-3"]

def find_db_versions_parallel(server_list):
    DB_version=[]
    cmd = "someway_of _connecting_to_db --server " + server_list +" --script /tmp/find_version.sql"
    db_vers = cmd
    DB_version.append([server_list,db_vers,"True"])
    print("Server_List_Item:::", server_list)
    return DB_version

def find_db_versions():
    headers = ["Server","DB Version","Load"]
    print("\nGathering Info. Grab a cup of Coffee!!!")
    pool = Pool(5)
    db_versions_computed = pool.map(find_db_versions_parallel,server_list)
    print ("\ndb_versions_computed:::\n", db_versions_computed)

def find_db_versions_iter():
    DB_version1=[]
    for i in range(len(server_list)):
        
        cmd = "someway_of _connecting_to_db --server " + server_list[i] +" --script /tmp/find_version.sql"
        db_vers = cmd
        DB_version1.append([server_list[i],db_vers,"True"])
    print("\n\nTraditiona Way:::\n",DB_version1)

find_db_versions()
find_db_versions_iter()
```

Debugging further shows extra layer nesting in the final list using which tabulate works.

***Output:***

```
Gathering Info. Grab a cup of Coffee!!!
Server_List_Item::: server-1
Server_List_Item::: server-3
Server_List_Item::: server-2
db_versions_computed:::
[[['server-1', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-1 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']], [['server-2', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-2 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']], [['server-3', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-3 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']]]
Traditiona Way:::
 [['server-1', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-1 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-2', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-2 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-3', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-3 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']]
```

Tried multiple things but am unable to understand why the extra layer nesting is happening. Is this because of **Pool**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you execute ...

```py
db_versions_computed = pool.map(find_db_versions_parallel,server_list)
```

...  your "worker function" `find_db_versions_parallel` is called multiple times each time being passed a single element of `server_list` and what is returned by the `map` call is a **list** of all the returned values from `find_db_versions_parallel`.

In the following corrected code I have modified some variable names to make it clearer what is being passed and returned:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

server_list = ["server-1","server-2","server-3"]

def find_db_versions_parallel(server):
    cmd = "someway_of _connecting_to_db --server " + server +" --script /tmp/find_version.sql"
    db_vers = cmd
    DB_version = [server, db_vers, "True"]
    #print("Server_List_Item:::", server_list)
    return DB_version

def find_db_versions():
    headers = ["Server","DB Version","Load"]
    print("\nGathering Info. Grab a cup of Coffee!!!")
    pool = Pool(5)
    db_version_list_computed = pool.map(find_db_versions_parallel, server_list)
    print ("\ndb_versions_computed:::\n", db_version_list_computed)
    return db_version_list_computed

def find_db_versions_iter():
    DB_version_list = []
    for i in range(len(server_list)):

        cmd = "someway_of _connecting_to_db --server " + server_list[i] +" --script /tmp/find_version.sql"
        db_vers = cmd
        DB_version_list.append([server_list[i], db_vers, "True"])
    print("\n\nTraditiona Way:::\n", DB_version_list)
    return DB_version_list

# Required for windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = find_db_versions()
    l2 = find_db_versions_iter()
    print(f'The two results are{" not" if l1 != l2 else ""} equal.')
```

Prints:

```None
Gathering Info. Grab a cup of Coffee!!!

db_versions_computed:::
 [['server-1', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-1 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-2', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-2 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-3', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-3 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']]


Traditiona Way:::
 [['server-1', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-1 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-2', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-2 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True'], ['server-3', 'someway_of _connecting_to_db --server server-3 --script /tmp/find_version.sql', 'True']]
The two results are equal.
```